# iOS app failing installation

Tags: iphone, ios

We've got a weird situation where a fairly alarming number of users are not being able to install a recent update to an app.

The app seems to download on the device and then fail during the install process.

So far we have not been able to find any detailed logs or information from an actual device, so at this stage the question is more about whether it could be something related to the app packaging.

Some facts:

1. The update works fine, thousands of users are installing it. Only a small percentage of users are experiencing the problem.
2. It doesn't seem to be device dependent.
3. The previous versions all updated fine.
4. There is very little difference between the previous update and this one (certainly know project/config changes to the packaging).
5. We built using the same profile.

Comment: I think I've heard of this happening if a node in the app store CDN has an issue with code signing or in some other way has a corrupt bundle. Without more logs from your users it will be tough to say though.

Comment: Do you have any way of knowing whether the failed updates come from the immediate prior version of your app, or an older version?

Comment: I've managed to track down an install log on an actual device and I'm seeing: verify_signer_identity: MISValidateSignatureAndCopyInfo failed

Strange how this works on most installs but not on others. I would suspect a signing issue, but given it works on most devices it seems to point more towards some kind of corruption.